# typescript tsc error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'

Tags: angularjs, jenkins, typescript, tsc

I am trying to build a typescript project with jenkins.
But when i run tsc I get errors regarding non-relative imports from typescript files.

Here is a excerpt from the build.

```
+ ls node_modules/@angular/
common
compiler
core
http
platform-browser
platform-browser-dynamic
router
router-deprecated
+ tsc
client/dev/marvel-app/app.component.ts(2,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
client/dev/marvel-app/app.component.ts(3,9): error TS2305: Module '"/root/.jenkins/jobs/marvel-encyclopedia/workspace/node_modules/@angular/router-deprecated/index"' has no exported member 'RouteConfig'.
client/dev/marvel-app/helpers/parallax.directive.ts(8,17): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
client/dev/marvel-app/modules/filter/filter.component.ts(1,51): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
client/dev/marvel-app/modules/go-back-up/go-back-up.component.ts(1,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
client/dev/marvel-app/modules/graph/graph.component.ts(1,100): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
client/dev/marvel-app/modules/grid/grid.component.ts(1,62): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
client/dev/marvel-app/modules/header/header.component.ts(1,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
client/dev/marvel-app/modules/navbar/navbar.component.ts(1,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
client/dev/marvel-app/modules/search/search.component.ts(1,51): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
client/dev/marvel-app/modules/search/search.component.ts(2,23): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/common'.
```

here is the content of my tsconfig.json file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "target": "es5",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
      "typings",
      "typings/main",
      "typings/main.d.ts"
    ],
    "filesGlob": [
      "**/*.ts",
      "typings/main",
      "typings/main.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

I tried locally on my mac and it works fine. Jenkins is located on a linux machine.

**EDIT**: Actually the error came from a bad installation of the node modules. deleting `node_modules` and re-installing fix that problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have tsconfig like the following:

```
 "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
      "typings",
      "typings/main",
      "typings/main.d.ts"
    ],
    "filesGlob": [
      "**/*.ts",
      "typings/main",
      "typings/main.d.ts"
    ]
```

Most likely `filesGlob` isn't support in your build process and `exclude` is kicking in. You are excluding `typings/main` (which are including in filesGlob and hence it works locally)